# Google Drive Emptied Trash, after 10minutes, those deleted forever files still appear when I perform list files using Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

As the title

Because my google drive has alot of files, so when I was debugging my Android app with Google Drive API, it takes long time to list all the files.

So I decided to clear 90% of my files into trash, then empty the trash. (Delete forever)

However, those "deleted forever" files still get returned when I perform list files using Google Drive API. Even after 10minutes or more.

Is this a normal phenomena?

Comment: Are you using any list parameters?

Comment: nope, I didn't use any list parameters.

when I try again after few hours, the "deleted forever" files do not get returned anymore.

but 10minutes(or more) after the "empty trashes", it still get returned.